# Can Xcode's 'Architecture' and 'Valid Architectures' exclude armv6 devices from downloading the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

We recently set the minimum iOS support to 4.0 and started using the LLVM compiler for a new update of a current available app.

Will setting 'Architecture' and 'Valid Architectures' to only armv7 exclude armv6 devices such as iPhone 3G from downloading the update?

I have tried with [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) but Apple does not let you set this for app updates, only for new apps, which is unfortunate.

We also don't have access to an armv6 device to test the app as I have read reports that the new compiler might cause some issues with this older architecture, thus we want to exclude armv6 from updating the app as we still have a small number of users running on armv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the minimum required OS to iOS 4.3. That will exclude all armv6 devices as Apple dropped armv6 in iOS 4.3.